# CaseIterable string enum is not showing their values according to their indexes SWIFT 5

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, enums

This is my `enum`, which is declared globally in my home view controller (Before `class HomeViewController: UIViewController,`)

```
enum HomeVCSectionTypes: String, CaseIterable {
    case mostPopularBoolValue = "mostPopularBoolValue"
    case discountedBoolValue = "discountedBoolValue"
    case newlyAddedBoolValue = "newlyAddedBoolValue"

    init?(id : Int) {
        switch id {
        case 1: self = .mostPopularBoolValue
        case 2: self = .discountedBoolValue
        case 3: self = .newlyAddedBoolValue
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And I am iterating through it in my view will appear like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    for sectionType in HomeVCSectionTypes.allCases {
        fetchData(homeVCSectionTypes: sectionType)
    }
}
```

But it is not showing the values according to their serial indexes. What am I missing here?

```
func fetchData(homeVCSectionTypes: HomeVCSectionTypes) {
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        objectArray.removeAll()

        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)

        dispatchQueue.async {
            let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("album").order(by: "timestamp", descending: true).whereField(homeVCSectionTypes.rawValue, isEqualTo: true).limit(to: 10)

            docRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
                var items = [ProductCategoryAlbum]()
                if snapshot.documents.count > 0 {
                    do {
                        for document in snapshot.documents {
                            let object = try document.decode(as: ProductCategoryAlbum.self)
                            items.append(object)
                        }
                        self.objectArray.append(HomeObject(sectionName: homeVCSectionTypes.rawValue, sectionObjects: items))
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.homeTableView.reloadData()
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.homeTableView.isHidden = true
                        self.noDataLabel.isHidden = false
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    }
                }
                semaphore.signal()
            }
            semaphore.wait()
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `fetchData()`, and how are the values displayed? – My guess: The data is fetched asynchronously, so that the order of responses can not be predicted.

Comment: Not related to your question but assigning the same string value to your cases is pointless

Comment: @MartinR Yes. I have updated my question.

Comment: @LeoDabus In this structure how would I show them according to the index value of my `enum`?

Comment: @Tulon you can simply add ```var intValue: Int``` property and switch self inside according to your init Int values